# Finding consumption function which maximizes utility

Tags: calculus-of-variations, utility, variational-analysis

I can across this question in my applied real analysis textbook that I'm having trouble with. It asks us to consider the utility function $U(C) = \sqrt{e^{-rt}C}$. I'm supposed to find the consumption function which maximizes the utility over time interval [0,T]:

$$\int^T_0 U(C(t))dt$$

I would really appreciate if someone could explain how to do this as the textbook does not do a very good job of explaining questions such as this. We are currently working on the calculus of variations.

Comment: What techniques are you supposed to use? Calculus of variations? Dynamical programming?

Comment: My apologies, I am supposed to use the calculus of variations. I added that as a tag but I should clarify in the question as well.

Comment: Oops I missed that. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No problem! Would you happen to know how to solve this?

Comment: Is there a constraint on $C$? If not, letting $C(t) = \alpha$ for all $t$ and sending $\alpha$ to $\infty$ leads to an unbounded sequence of utilities.

Comment: No, I do not believe that there is a constraint on $\alpha$. However, the textbook does provide a solution (for all it's worth): $C_0e^{(2i-r)}t$

Comment: Hm. I would double check for a constraint—maybe by looking through your book’s description of utility functions. The ability to consume in an unbounded manner might lead to unbounded utility, and something needs to make the counterexample I posed fail to apply. Unfortunately I do not know off the top of my head what constraint would yield the solution in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of what you could do given a constraint. Consider the constraint $\int_0^T C dt = C_0.$ Let $C$ be a function satisfying the constraint. Then pick an arbitrary perturbation $f$ that respects the constraint, i.e. $\int C+\epsilon f dt = C_0$, which implies $\int_0^T f dt = 0.$

Then one can show that
$$ \int_0^T U(C+\epsilon f) dt - \int_0^T U(C) dt = \epsilon \int_0^T \sqrt{e^{-rt}} f C^{-1/2} dt + O(\epsilon^2). $$

So the derivative of the objective function at $C$ in the direction $f$ is
$$ \int_0^T \sqrt{e^{-rt}} f C^{-1/2} dt.$$

For us to have a local minimum or maximum, we want the derivative to be zero for all $f$ that respect the constraint. For this to happen, we need to have $C =  k e^{-rt}$ for some constant $k$. We can find the value of $k$ by making sure that the constraint is satisfied.

The above is not rigorous, but it is the correct outline of how a rigorous argument could go. I'm happy to elaborate on details and why this is the correct approach if needed.